# Show a sub menu when click on tab bar item

Tags: ios

I am using tab bar controller and it will get 5 tabs.
First 4 tabs will get their own view controller, but at the 5th tab I need to do like a popup menu or slide menu. It will overlap another view controller when I click on the 5th tab and I click again this menu will hide.

[image]

Comment: could you elaborate what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the present screen the level of hierarchy is not properly managed, You can do something like.

1. I would encourage you to put the other sub menu items in a hamburger menu.

   i.e., contact us, about us, or whatever you feel are relevant.

[image]

2. If there is no frequent navigation between the menu items. You can incorporate all menu items in hamburger menu.

[image]

3. You can try something like scroll able tab bar in material Design(If acceptable) with arrow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can i do like click on tab bar, the slide menu just show out?

Comment: just check the edits